# Usage of the word "binding"

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, terminology

First of all, this is really two questions: a specific question and the meta question: where do I ask questions that are of the same type as the specific question?

I am only expecting an answer to the meta question from this site, unless this site is the answer to the meta question.

**Meta question**

Where do you ask questions about the usage of different programming words? For example, "static" means many things in many different contexts - I know what static means now but where would I have asked a clarification question about it when I was first learning?  Also, where's a Stack Exchange site that you can ask what certain abbreviations mean? E.g. "xjc" is a command line tool that I know what it does but I still don't know what the exact letters stand for.

Summary: where can you ask questions about programming terminology? A specific example is below.

**Specific question**

What's the difference between the use of the word binding in the following two contexts?

> The latest LWJGL snapshot (3.1.1 build 5) includes **bindings** to Assimp, a library to import and export various well-known 3D model formats in a uniform manner.

and

> The Java DOM and SAX parsing APIs are lower-level APIs to parse XML documents, while JAXB (Java API for XML **Binding**) is a higher-level API for converting XML elements and attributes to a Java object hierarchy (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2):

It's [acceptable on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), if it's not written so it's [opinion based](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053062/3648282):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Stack Overflow has a tag for [binding](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/binding/info), and over [109K](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B*binding*%5D&mixed=0) questions and answers on the subject, but it is preferred to use one of the more than [30 other](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) more specific tags that contain "binding" in their name.

Searching for both the tags [[binding] and [terminology]](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbinding%5D%20%5Bterminology%5D&mixed=0) results in 10 hits.

It's [off topic on English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site.
>
> - Naming, including naming programming variables/classes

Comment: I'm a little confused by the last bit. This isn't about "naming" at all, is it?